# how to change the border colour of ng-select component to red?

Tags: angular, css, bootstrap-4, angular-ngselect

The select component in my angular html template is displaying fine. However I want to display this component with a red border, currently it is displayed in grey color. I am not able to achieve this.

I'm using Angular 5

```
<ng-select class="custom" [searchable]="true" formControlName="contactList" [items]="contactLists" 
     bindLabel="name" 
     placeholder="{{ 'PLACEHOLDERS.CONTACT_LIST' | translate }}" [compareWith]="compareResource">
</ng-select>
```

the custom css is defined in file and it is as follows

```
.ng-select.custom {
    min-height: 0px;
    max-width: 350px;
}
.ng-select.dropdown {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: have you tried adding the: !important flag at the css??

Comment: could you detail a bit more please . where should place the !important.. thank you

Comment: you should place !important like this:
.ng-select.custom {
        min-height: 0px !important;
        max-width: 350px !important;
    }
.ng-select.dropdown {
    border: 1px solid red !important;
} 

by the way I changed you last line, from 'solid black' to 'solid red' because you asked for red color.

Comment: Can you share working fiddle? Thanks

Comment: I can't because I don't know how is your code working, if you can share to us a working code. Then i can help you to achieve your goal.

Comment: how can i share . which tools should i use to share ? is github ok ?? @Alberto AM & Hassan Siddiqui .. thank you so much

Comment: i have shared my code here https://github.com/prasanthmp500/mep.git .  checkout the pbranch fixingHelp . the files you would be looking is src/app/flights/flight-form/flight-form-target-step/flight-form-target-step.component.html ( search for ng-select)  and the css is 
src/app/flights/flight-form/flight-form-target-step/flight-form-target-step.component.scss ... many thanks

Comment: @prasanth you can use a nice web called: stackblitz . Which provides an easy way to share you code.

Comment: @AlbertoAM using important helped me to solve the problem ..thank you so much

Answer (score 4):

What you're probably looking for is called `::ng-deep`*. 
check the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) for further details.
*be aware that it's in a deprecated state at the moment.

```
::ng-deep .ng-select.custom {
        min-height: 0px;
        max-width: 350px;
}

::ng-deep .ng-select.dropdown {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also override the SCSS variable in your styles.scss

```
$ng-select-highlight: #6200ee !default;
@import "~@ng-select/ng-select/scss/material.theme";
```

Answer (score 1):

add this style in css/scss file of your component.
[get more info](https://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-ng-select-validation-multiselection-custom-property-binding-and-checkboxes/)

```
/* 
    go red when touched
*/

/* Border Color */
.ng-select.ng-invalid.ng-touched .ng-select-container{
    border-color: red;
}

/* Arrow Color */
.ng-select.ng-invalid.ng-touched .ng-arrow-wrapper .ng-arrow{
    border-color: red transparent transparent
}
/* Placeholder Color */
.ng-select.ng-invalid.ng-touched .ng-select-container .ng-placeholder{
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css you are targeting ".ng-select", have you tried targeting it as an element and not a class?

```
 ng-select.custom {
     min-height: 0px;
     max-width: 350px;
 }

 ng-select.dropdown {
     border: 1px solid black;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is a problem realted to angular viewencapsulation and browser css specificy.
I aslo seen that you use  `border: 1px solid black;` and not red as you mentioned in the question.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-viewencapsulation-in-angular

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<ng-multiselect-dropdown #multiSelect [placeholder]="'Select Service'" [settings]="dropdownSettings" class="custom-dropdown"
  [data]="dropdownList">
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

Provide a custom class  e.g. custom-dropdown and then in your styles.scss override it, for example

```css
.custom-dropdown .multiselect-dropdown {
    position: relative;
    font-size: 0.9375rem !important;
    font-weight: 600 !important;
    color: #757575 !important;
    font-family: "Gilroy-SemiBold", "Arial", serif !important;
    .dropdown-btn {
        border: 1px solid #red !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For setting border color of ng-select component, you need to set border color to ng-container -

```
.ng-select .ng-select-container {
    border: 1px solid #2aa0d0;
}
```